# How to implement list item deletion for all argument modes?

Tags: prolog, sequence, termination, failure-slice, logical-purity

The following Prolog program defines a predicate `deleted/3` for deleting all the occurrences of the item passed in first argument from the list passed in second argument and results in the list passed in third argument:

```
deleted(_, [], []).
deleted(X, [X|Y], Z) :-
  deleted(X, Y, Z).
deleted(U, [V|W], [V|X]) :-
  deleted(U, W, X),
  U \= V.
```

1. It works with queries in this argument mode:

```
?- deleted(a, [a, b, a], [b]).
   true
;  false.
```

2. It also works with queries in this argument mode:

```
?- deleted(X, [a, b, a], [b]).
   X = a
;  false.
```

3. It also works with queries in this argument mode:

```
?- deleted(a, [a, b, a], Z).
   Z = [b]
;  false.
```

4. It also works with queries in this argument mode:

```
?- deleted(X, [a, b, a], Z).
   X = a, Z = [b]
;  X = b, Z = [a, a]
;  false.
```

5. It also works with queries in this argument mode:

```
?- deleted(a, Y, Z).
   Y = Z, Z = []
;  Y = [a], Z = []
;  Y = [a, a], Z = []
;  Y = [a, a, a], Z = []
;  Y = [a, a, a, a], Z = []
;  …
```

6. It also works with queries in this argument mode:

```
?- deleted(X, Y, Z).
   Y = Z, Z = []
;  Y = [X], Z = []
;  Y = [X, X], Z = []
;  Y = [X, X, X], Z = []
;  Y = [X, X, X, X], Z = []
;  …
```

7. But it exhausts resources with queries in this argument mode:

```
?- deleted(a, Y, [b]).
Stack limit (0.2Gb) exceeded
  Stack sizes: local: 0.2Gb, global: 28.1Mb, trail: 9.3Mb
  Stack depth: 1,225,203, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 1,225,183
  Possible non-terminating recursion:
    [1,225,203] deleted(a, _1542, [length:1])
    [1,225,202] deleted(a, [length:1|_1584], [length:1])
```

8. It also exhausts resources with queries in this argument mode:

```
?- deleted(X, Y, [b]).
Stack limit (0.2Gb) exceeded
  Stack sizes: local: 0.2Gb, global: 28.1Mb, trail: 9.3Mb
  Stack depth: 1,225,179, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 1,225,159
  Possible non-terminating recursion:
    [1,225,179] deleted(_1562, _1564, [length:1])
    [1,225,178] deleted(_1596, [length:1|_1606], [length:1])
```

How to implement list item deletion for all argument modes?

Comment: It doesn't really work in `deleted(a, Y, Z)` and `deleted(X, Y, Z)` modes either. If it works, queries like this should succeed: `deleted(a, Y, Z), Y = [a, b, a], Z = [b].`

Comment: Are you looking for one main predicate that determines the mode by inspecting the the input and then picking one of a few support predicates or are you looking for a single predicate that uses dif/2 or constraints or something similar? In other words what is the reason you want the predicate to do this? Are you going down the rabbit hole because you can?

Comment: @GuyCoder I am looking for the latter. I would like to avoid metalogic.

Comment: @GuyCoder I don’t know for `dif/2` but I would like to avoid testing the type of the arguments with `var/1`, `nonvar/1`, or `ground/1`. In other words, I would like a purely declarative solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851927/2326961), not like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68864099/2326961).

Comment: So then `deleted(a,L,[])` could result in an infinite list? Think about it. Is that what you really want.

Comment: @GuyCoder Yes that is what I want.

Comment: `dif/2` is perfect (but does not solve everything)

Comment: For `deleted(a,L,[b,c])` where should `a` be inserted? In the front, end, middle, randomly? Basically for each insert there are multiple combinations of answers. Which one is correct according to your specification?

Comment: On interest: [select/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select/3) It is similar to your question but does not create infinite list. It will only add the single item once and then the query is considered solved.

Comment: FYI. I am not trying to solve this, I am just curious to see if an acceptable solution is posted that covers all of the possible conditions. Thus the questions about the possible conditions and solutions. Personally I would use select/3 in real world code and be satisfied unless there was a need for what you seek.

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider the question `How to implement list item deletion for all argument modes?` Is what you seek really `deletion`? In other modes it is not deletion but insertion or even relationships as you saw with `Y = [X, X, X]`.

Comment: @false [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) does not use semicolons to separate answers because it uses background color for this role. But thanks for adding them as we do not have that visual clue on Stack Overflow. However you did not add indentation for single answers, was it on purpose?

Comment: @Maggyero: SWI under Linux does produce the semicolons but they are put at the end of the line which suggests to beginners that the semicolon means something similar to C/C++/Java etc. As for the indentation otherwise: No, not really. As for the toplevel alone, Scryer has the nicest indentation.

Comment: @GuyCoder ‘For `deleted(a,L,[b,c])` where should `a` be inserted? In the front, end, middle, randomly?’ Front, end, middle, combinations of these, and repetitions of these.

Comment: @false Alright. I have just added indentation everywhere and used three-space indentation to align answers with queries, like in the README of [Scryer Prolog](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog). Also I like the empty lines between answers that you used, it is easier to read than Scryer Prolog output which stacks answers without blank space, so I kept your version.

Comment: While StackOverflow is not the best place to learn Prolog, answers by selected users are worthy of studying. For this question the answers by [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4609915/repeat) for `list` and `purity` are of value. Here is a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4609915+%5Bprolog%5D+%5Blist%5D+is%3Aanswer) I used. It does have some answer that are off topic but better to grab more than remove something that is of value.  continued.

Comment: I would note that the tag  [logical-purity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logical-purity) should be on the answers you seek but sally it is missing from many.

Comment: Are you aware of how close your code is to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55030527/1243762) - #4 in list?

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks for the links. My program is the same as program #4 in repeat’s answer, except that I am using `\=/2` instead of `dif/2`, but it does not make a difference: both programs exhausts resources for the last two queries in this post.

Comment: @GuyCoder FYI, a solution has been posted.

Comment: `a solution has been posted` I see but it did not pass your requirement. From earlier comments.  My clarification, `For deleted(a,L,[b,c]) where should a be inserted?` In the front, end, middle, randomly?  Your requirement  `Front, end, middle, combinations of these, and repetitions of these.`  As it is your question you can move the goal post.

Comment: @GuyCoder It passes my requirements. But you cannot see it from the first solutions where `a` is inserted at the front since there is an infinity of these front solutions, before the middle and end solutions are generated.

Comment: `But you cannot see it from the first solutions where a is inserted at the front since there is an infinity of these front solutions, before the middle and end solutions are generated.` I agree. Perhaps the answer should note using, `length(L,N),deleted(a,L,[b,c]).` I don't plan to add another answer with that detail but hopefully @repeat will modify his answer mentioning that.

Comment: Do you plan on adding logical-purity as a tag to your question?

Comment: @GuyCoder `length(L, N), deleted(a, L , [b, c]).` Excellent remark, I did not think about adding a length constraint to generate solutions in a specific order (by length). Let’s ask repeat what he thinks about this.

Comment: @GuyCoder My question was not specifically about logical purity but about non termination. However it turns out the solution involves using logically pure predicates, so yes, I am adding this tag. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: For `Let’s ask repeat what he thinks about this.`, since you have accepted an answer, it would be proper StackOverflow etiquette to ask a new question and reference this one. That way you and repeat can also gain more points. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Intro

Pure Prolog conjunctions and disjunctions *are*, in fact, commutative and associative.

This allows us to ignore clause and goal order, provided that *all* answer sequences are *finite*.

When queries have infinite solution sets, Prolog may need to *systematically enumerate* infinite answer sequences.

## The fix

To help Prolog find answers for above “problematic” queries, swap the two recursive rules:

```
deleted(_,[],[]).
deleted(U,[V|W],[V|X]) :-  % this clause was last
   dif(U,V),
   deleted(U,W,X).
deleted(X,[X|Y],Z) :-
   deleted(X,Y,Z).
```

## Demo

Let’s run your queries *again* with above code changes!

The *finite* ones work like before<sup>1</sup>:

```
?- deleted(a,[a,b,a],[b]).         % Q1
   true
;  false.

?- deleted(X,[a,b,a],[b]).         % Q2
   X = a
;  false.

?- deleted(a,[a,b,a],Z).           % Q3
   Z = [b]
;  false.

?- deleted(X,[a,b,a],Z).           % Q4
   Z = [a,b,a], dif(X,a), dif(X,b)
;  Z = [a,  a],               X=b
;  Z = [  b  ],     X=a
;  false.
```

Some *infinite* ones were okay before—they *still* are:

```
?- deleted(a,Y,Z).                 % Q5
   Y = Z, Z = []
;  Y = Z, Z = [_A],       dif(_A,a)
;  Y = Z, Z = [_A,_B],    dif(_A,a), dif(_B,a)
;  Y = Z, Z = [_A,_B,_C], dif(_A,a), dif(_B,a), dif(_C,a)
;  …

?- deleted(X,Y,Z).                 % Q6
   Y = Z, Z = []
;  Y = Z, Z = [_A],       dif(X,_A)
;  Y = Z, Z = [_A,_B],    dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B) 
;  Y = Z, Z = [_A,_B,_C], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B), dif(X,_C)
;  …
```

Some *infinite* ones used to be “problematic”—not anymore:

```
?- deleted(a,Y,[b]).               % Q7
   Y = [b]
;  Y = [b,a]
;  Y = [b,a,a]
;  Y = [b,a,a,a]
;  …

?- deleted(X,Y,[b]).               % Q8
   Y = [b],         dif(X,b)
;  Y = [b,X],       dif(X,b)
;  Y = [b,X,X],     dif(X,b)
;  Y = [b,X,X,X],   dif(X,b)
;  Y = [b,X,X,X,X], dif(X,b)
;  …
```

## Analysis

Now, `?- deleted(X,Y,[b]).` makes Prolog give us answers.

But why did we run [out-of-memory](/questions/tagged/out-of-memory)?
How come it did not work?

To explain this, let’s take a step back: the default / vanilla / out-of-the-box [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) of many<sup>2</sup> Prolog systems initially runs each query until it discovers *either* (0) **finite failure** *or* (1) **the 1st answer**<sup>3</sup>.

Before the fix, we observed *neither*. Why not?

0. Why no **finite failure**?

   `deleted(a,[a,b,a],[b])` holds true.

   Therefore, the *more general* `deleted(X,Y,[b])` *must not* fail.
1. Why no **(1st) answer**?

   Prolog proceeds depth-first, top-down, left-to-right.

   So when …

   ```
       ?- deleted(X,Y,[b]).
   ```

   … “meets” …

   ```
       deleted(X,[X|Y],Z) :-
          deleted(X,Y,Z).
   ```

   … inside the Prolog machine, the following happens:

   - A *choicepoint* is created for saving the information—to be used upon backtracking—that another clause *could* have been selected.
   - Next, Prolog proceeds with a recursive goal which is just like the original one: we are *no closer* to an answer, as the 3rd argument—the *only* instantiated one—stays *exactly* the same.

   Eventually, this loop runs out of memory—which is exactly the behavior that you observed.

If we swap two recursive clauses, the following clause becomes our top-most recursive clause:

```
deleted(U,[V|W],[V|X]) :-
   dif(U,V),
   deleted(U,W,X).
```

Now, something *is* going on with the 3rd argument: Prolog recursively walks down the single-linked list until `[]` (or a free logical variable) is reached. Only then can Prolog make use of the fact `deleted(_,[],[]).` and give us an answer.

---

**Footnotes**:

1. In fact *better*, as we preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) by using `dif/2` for expressing syntactic term inequality.

   More on `dif/2`: [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)
2. All [command-line-interface](/questions/tagged/command-line-interface) based Prolog systems I have ever used.
3. *Not* stopping at the 1st answer is way better for code quality—particularly in regard to universal termination properties.

   [GUPU](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/gupu/), an excellent [environment specialized for Prolog and constraint programming courses](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/gupu-wlpe2002.pdf), does the right thing—*by default*!

   “[Answer substitutions are displayed in **chunks of five**.](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/gupu/query2)”

Comment: GuyCoder made an excellent remark: the query `deleted(a, Y, [b, c]).` returns solutions *by position*: `Y = [b, c]; Y = [b, c, a]; Y = [b, c, a, a]; Y = [b, c, a, a, a]; Y = [b, c, a, a, a, a]; …`, while the query `length(Y, _), deleted(a, Y, [b, c]).` returns solutions *by length*: `Y = [b, c]; Y = [b, c, a]; Y = [b, a, c]; Y = [a, b, c]; Y = [b, c, a, a]; Y = [b, a, c, a]; Y = [b, a, a, c]; Y = [a, b, c, a]; Y = [a, b, a, c]; Y = [a, a, b, c]; …`, which is a nicer ordering. Should the predicate `length/2` be included in the predicate `deleted/3`, or should it be left outside in queries?

Comment: @Maggyero. I took me a moment to grasp what you actually meant when you wrote (1) "by position" and (2) "by length" :-) Both are usually referred to as "search algorithms" or "*search strategies*": (1) is called [*depth-first search* with chronological backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). (2) is called [*iterative deepening* depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). Want to know more? If so, summon the Power of Prolog and read the chapter [Sorting and Searching with Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/sorting)!

Comment: @Maggyero. I'd rather leave it out, document the behavior and implementation limitations, and use iterative deepening only when needed. YMMV!